# Iterate through string.find in Lua

Tags: lua

Currently I work on a project within the game Minecraft and OpenComputers. The main coding language is Lua.

Now, I need to find a nice solution to iterate through a string.

My current solution looks like this:

```
local config = "key1=type1\nkey2=type2\nkey3=type3"
local lines = {}
while true do
    local length = config:len()
    local s, f = config:find("\n")
    if s ~= nil then
        table.insert(lines, config:sub(1, s-1))
        config = config:sub(f+1, length)
    else
        table.insert(lines, config)
        break
    end
end
```

In this example I have a static string in the variable `config` but in the real code I read the lines from a config file.

My solution works, but I think it can be cleaner. Is there a cleaner solution?

Comment: If it works but you want to see if it could be cleaner, you should request a review on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @StephenOstermiller in the future, please don't use Code Review as a reason to close a question. Evaluate the request and use a reason like *too broad*, *primarily opinion-based*, etc. Please see the section **What you should not do** in [this answer to _A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users_](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778/120114)

Comment: Okay guys i'm sorry for my mistake on stackoverflow. Thank you for the information on "what i should not do" :)

Comment: @ChristianNill Sam Onela's comment was actually directed at Stephen Ostermiller.  Specifically, the part in that post where it says *"Not all questions about analyzing code are off-topic on Stack Overflow, and not all code review requests are on-topic on Code Review"*.  This was probably fine on both, quite frankly.  I see a lot of people who conclude that just because something is on-topic on another site that it is automatically off-topic here, which is not the case.

Comment: Ah okay. Then i just misunderstood this. Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to iterate over the lines in a file, use `io.lines`:

```
local lines = {}
for l in io.lines("config.txt") do
    table.insert(lines, l)
end
```

Comment: The answer was soooo easy... Thank you very much. Sometimes i do not see the tree within a forest. Thank you